# Exercise regarding normal matrices and their spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I hope could get a few hints to this exercise

Let $T\in M_n (\mathbb{C})$ be a normal matrix.

1. Let $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$, where $\sigma(T)$ is the spectrum of $T$. Argue that $1_{\{\lambda\}}\in C(\sigma (T))$.
2. Set $P_\lambda=\Psi(1_{\{\lambda\}})$, where $\Psi$ is a $C^*$-isomorphism from $C(\sigma(T))$ onto $\text{Alg}_{C^*}(I,T)$. Prove that $P_\lambda$ is an orthogonal projection.
3. Prove that the range $R(P_\lambda)$ of $P_\lambda$,is contained in the eigenspace $E_\lambda$.

Comment: What is $1_{\{\lambda\}}$? What is $C(\sigma (T))$?